# Carregar vários CSV concatenados de uma só vez em Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Fala pessoal, tranquilo?

Existe uma maneira mais fácil de carregar .csv concatenados de uma só vez ao invés de fazer o procedimento abaixo?

```
z1 = pd.read_csv('arquivo1.csv')
z2 = pd.read_csv('arquivo2.csv')
z3 = pd.read_csv('arquivo3.csv')
z4 = pd.read_csv('arquivo4.csv')
z5 = pd.read_csv('arquivo5.csv')
z6 = pd.read_csv('arquivo6.csv')
z7 = pd.read_csv('arquivo7.csv')
z8 = pd.read_csv('arquivo8.csv')

objs = [z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6 ,z7 ,z8]

pd.concat(objs, axis=0)
```

Comment: Você quer um dataframe que una todos os arquivos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O procedimento é esse mesmo, mas dá pra toná-lo 1 linha de código utilizando o potencial do MAP para aplicar a função a toda a matriz de nome de arquivos:

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob('arquivo*.csv')))
```

Explore um pouco mais do potencial do map e do reduce para trabalhar com matrizes/listas, a combinação disso tornará seu código menor e mais performático

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Souza! Funcionou bem! Obrigado também pela dica do map reduce!

Answer (score 0):

Pode pode fazer isso usando `glob`

```
import glob
arquivos = glob.glob('arquivo*.csv')
# 'arquivos' agora é um array com o nome de todos os .csv que começam com 'arquivo'
array_df = []

for x in arquivos:
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(x)
    array_df.append(temp_df)

df = pd.concat(array_df, axis=0)
```

Comment: obrigado Terry pela ajuda ! Funcionou bem!